# How to switch background image during video compositing?

Tags: compositing-nodes

[image: My Problem During Compositing]

Greetings,

as you can see in the picture, I want this picture to be background image for my amateur video.

Any advices?

Comment: Can you provide a higher resolution of your node setup? As here the properties are unreadable.

Answer (score 2):

The order for the input sockets for the Alpha Over matters. In this case they are reversed and need to be switched.

**The top socket is used for the background image, the bottom socket for the foreground (or image to be placed over using the alpha channel)**.

[image]

[image]

See:

[Background image shows in front of 3D objects, not behind them.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38333/background-image-shows-in-front-of-3d-objects-not-behind-them/38334#38334)

Comment: Read also: [how to put animated background to keyed video](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/197496/how-to-put-animated-background-to-keyed-video/204808#204808)